# Generating JobId for Android Jobscheduler services

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, hash-code-uniqueness

I have multiple JobServices in my app. As per the Android docs, JobId for each JobService has to be unique per uid. In order to avoid collisions, I am using unique String hashcode as my JobId. this can lead to negative JobIds as well. Is this the right way of generating JobIds?

Comment: "I have multiple JobServices in my app" -- eventually, consider switching to `WorkManager`. "In order to avoid collisions, I am using unique String hashcode as my JobId... Is this the right way of generating JobIds?" -- IMHO, no. Use `final static int` values (e.g., start at `1337` and work your way up from there). Or, you could try using `id` resource values, though I am uncertain what value that adds over just using simple `int` values that you code yourself.

Comment: I tried following this article also https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/working-with-multiple-jobservices.html. But I want to understand how he wants us to generate short objectId (channelId), which we can prefix with job_type.

Comment: The code in that blog post is awful.

Comment: Even i thought so. Can you please explain me how you gave the number 1337? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: 1337 is [just a number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet). It has no particular meaning, other than I tend to use it for these sorts of locally-unique numbers that we need to come up with ourselves.

Comment: But that does not guaranty the uniqueness of the JobId value I guess. Is there no better way we can choose a JobId?

Comment: "But that does not guaranty the uniqueness of the JobId value I guess" -- it simply needs to be unique within your app. I don't know why you somehow need this to be *more* unique.

Comment: Then should I just hardcode some int constants as JobId?

Comment: In general, yes. Most apps only have a handful of known jobs. The post that you linked to is focused on a case where the distinct jobs is not knowable at compile time, and even then I would use a better algorithm than what they used.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so one way of doing it,maybe the only way(If you want complete automated numbers without using an arrayList of previous numbers) is to use a static field.So using this technique you'll have:

```
public class MyJobService extends JobService {
    public static int jobIb = 0;
...

    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        jobIb++;
```

now each time creating a job info just use:

```
new JobInfo.Builder(MyJobService.jobIb,componentName).setExtras(bundle).setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY).build()
```

So this is the way to do it if you have only one type of JobService,if you have more simply call `MyJobService.jobIb++;`
on their onStartJob as well you'll be fine.